# using grep case scenario on character sequence

Tags: regex, grep

trying to capture the string `#hīc"` using the grep expression `grep -r -i '#\w[ēāīōū]*\w+\"' *.html` over a directory. I tested the regex string on the [regex101 site](https://regex101.com/r/i530hB/1) and it works there. Grep 3.4 vs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is the `+`. BRE in POSIX grep does not have `+` for 1 or more and that would be interpreted as a literal `'+'` that grep would be looking for.

Neither is the `\w` shorthand character class supported in POSIX grep (though it is not forbidden and some platforms, such as BSD and OS X do have `\w` support.)

The standard POSIX character class would be `[:alnum:]` with some supporting `[:word:]` or `[:name:]`, depending on your local settings and grep, as the equivalent of `\w`. Other classes can be seen [HERE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) and [HERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html). There are difference in those character classes as well such as if `_` is included in the class and whether non ascii letters are included.

For the same match (assuring 1 or more rather than 0 or more for `*` alone) use `\w\w*` instead of `\w+` (Or `[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*` if your grep does not support `\w`)

This works with BSD / Mac grep:

```
echo 'line 1
line 2
#hīc"
line 4' | grep '#\w[ēāīōū]*\w\w*"'
#hīc"
```

Or use the PCRE engine in GNU grep for PCRE compatible regex. That is what is used in regex101.

```
echo 'line 1
line 2
#hīc"
line 4' | ggrep -P '#\w[ēāīōū]*\w+"'
#hīc"
```

But that `-P` is in GNU grep only; not in POSIX.

Comment: The `\w` notation isn't a meaningful part of a POSIX BRE either: see [Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for the reminder. Since BSD grep [does support](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) `\w` I forget that POSIX does not.

Comment: That's the trouble with extensions — it's hard to keep track of what's what.  I just had to undo a change at work because the code has to work on Solaris 10 still, and `sed` on Solaris 10 (still) does not recognize `[[:space:]]` etc.  You mention `[:word:]` and `[:name:]` — again, those are not POSIX standard — see the regex link I quoted before, which lists: `[:alnum:]`, `[:cntrl:]`, `[:lower:]`, `[:space:]`, `[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]`, `[:print:]`, `[:upper:]`, `[:blank:]`, `[:graph:]`, `[:punct:]`, `[:xdigit:]`.